# Android Html parsing and FBReader - ebook parsing

Tags: android, parsing, html-parsing, epub, ebook-reader

I am modifying code of FBReader. I want to parse few more tags and attributes like **<'center>** tag, **isFullPage** attribute, but I failed to find the classes and parsing methods. I found few packages for parsing, I tried to edit them but I didn't get any output. I tried to debug the code and also prints logs. But all time there is no logs.

```
   org.geometerplus.fbreader.formats.fb2, 
   org.geometerplus.fbreader.formats.html, 
   org.geometerplus.fbreader.formats.oeb, 
   org.geometerplus.fbreader.formats.pdb, 
   org.geometerplus.zlibrary.core.html,
```

**HtmlReader.java** (package - org.geometerplus.zlibrary.core.html) have implemented methods -

```
public void startDocumentHandler();
public void endDocumentHandler();
public void startElementHandler(String tag, int offset, ZLHtmlAttributeMap attributes);
public void endElementHandler(String tag);
public void byteDataHandler(byte[] ch, int start, int length);
public void entityDataHandler(String entity);
```

FBreader Source Code - [site](http://fbreader.org/FBReaderJ) and [github code](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ).

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a simple xml/html parser?

Comment: Because FBReader Application parsing allmost html/xml tags that is required for my app. Now I want to parse some tags, that Parser of FBReader is not parsing. But I didn't find the code, where FBreader is parsing tags.